# How can I avoid reputation increasing when that vote didn't decrease the reputation?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

I'm working on a project and I've faced with a logical problem.

Our project is a question and answer website. Something exactly like StackOverflow. The problem is about *voting* system. All policies are exactly like SO *(each downvote `-2` rep, each upvote on question `+5`, on answer `+10` and etc)*

Ok, assume this: A user has `1` rep, and he asks a question. His question earns 1 downvote. My trigger would handle the reputations:

```
UPDATE users SET reputation = GREATEST(reputation - 2, 1) WHERE id = new.user_id
```

So the number of his reputation will be still `1`. Now if that downvote be taken back, this trigger will increase his reputations:

```
UPDATE users SET reputation = reputation + 2 WHERE id = new.user_id
```

So the number of his reputation will be `3` *(which shouldn't be)*. It's a logical problem. Is there any idea how can I handle that? Or how SO handles that?

Comment: Maybe one thing to do is having the reputation having the real number, and the display would show 1 if real rep is below... But that would result in sometimes the user having to gain more than 1 rep to get to 2...

Comment: @MartinVerjans I thought about your idea already .. that's not what SO does and doesn't sounds nice to me. thx anyway

Comment: You can store the actual value in the table and use the greatest function when retrieveing the values.

Answer (score 1):

Use a reputation transaction-based table instead:

```
create table user_rep (user_id int, rep_change int, rep_date datetime)
```

instead of updating a static table, insert a transaction into this table and join to the users table

```
select user_id, sum(rep_change) as total_rep
from user_rep
group by user_id
```